# Laravel al usar logout redirecionar a pagina login

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Mi intención es que al presionar el boton logout me redireccione a la pantalla de loginform.blade con la sesión concluida en mi proyecto laravel

mi boton en logout en \resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php es :

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
        onclick="event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                    {{ __('Logout') }}
    </a>

    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
        @csrf
    </form>
</div>
```

se que redirecciona al controlador \app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php :

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```

actual mente me redireciona a home.blade y al ser nuevo trabajando sobre laravel no entiendo muy bien como funciona la parte de autentificación y destrucción de sesiones

Answer (score 0):

Sobreescribe el método loggedOut:

En `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`:

```
protected function loggedOut(Request $request) {
    return redirect('/login');
}
```